# Is there a way to force user having an new password with TYPO3 felogin/femanager?

Tags: typo3, change-password, felogin

we'd like to implement an obligatory update of given passwords by frontend user.
Our setting is the follow: TYPO3 8.7 / femanager 3.3.0
Any ideas or do we just miss a feature?
Many greetings
Daniel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thx for your hint. Try to doin' better next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another TYPO3 extension dealing with this issue: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/feloginforceupdate/

It depends on ext:femanager and is compatible with TYPO3 7.x but I got it running with TYPO3 8.7 without hassle.

Comment: you will need a scheduler task which resets the flag for all users which have not changed their password for n days (how can you decide when the last password change did happen?) instead of a boolean flag, use a date for the last passwordchange.

Comment: EXT:feloginforceupdate extends table fe_users by a field `changed_data` containing a timestamp to determine if the user already made changes. This is done via a SignalSlot Dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

There is an old extension (up to 6.2) which handles password expiration: [ext:lwpasswordexpire](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/lwpasswordexpire/).

- Either you motivate the author to do an update
- or you give the author a pullrequest
- or you get the idea to implement it anew in your installation
- or you extend `ext:femanager` with password expiration handling